# My {title} tags are not showing in IE10

Tags: templates, title

Bear with me as I am brand new to expression engine and PHP in general but the headers on these pages are not showing up in IE10...running it in compatibility mode fixes it but this needs to not happen. Id like to attempt to find the problem myself so here is a sample page starting at line 1:

```
 {assign_variable:sectionID="products"}
{assign_variable:pageID="index"}
{assign_variable:entryID="32"}
{assign_variable:subnav="n"}

{assign_variable:sectionTitle="Products"}
{assign_variable:pageTitle="-"}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head> 
 {embed="includes/browser-title-tag" pageTitle="{pageTitle}" sectionTitle="    {sectionTitle}"}

{exp:weblog:entries weblog="static_content" entry_id="32"}
<meta name="keywords" content="{sc_meta_tags}" />
<meta name="description" content="{sc_meta_description}" />
{/exp:weblog:entries}

{embed="includes/global-head"}


</head>
<body class="{sectionID}">
{!-- hook to put anything necessary right after the opening body tag --}
{embed="includes/global-page-top"}

    {embed="includes/global-header"}

    {embed="products/subnav" catID="0"}

<div id="centering-content-wrapper">

    <div id="content-wrapper">

        <div id="main-content">
            {!-- shows plain content --}        
            {embed='includes/plain-content' entryID="{entryID}" sectionTitle="{sectionTitle}" sectionID="{sectionID}" pageID="{pageID}" subnav="{subnav}"  pageTitle="{pageTitle}" }

            <dl>
{!-- Commercial Lines --}
            {exp:weblog:entries weblog="products" entry_id="50"}
                <dt><a href="{title_permalink=/products/product/}">    {title}</a></dt>
                <dd>{prod_short_desc}</dd>
            {/exp:weblog:entries}

{!-- Personal Lines --}
            {exp:weblog:entries weblog="products" entry_id="51"}
                <dt><a href="{title_permalink=/products/product/}">{title}</a></dt>
                <dd>{prod_short_desc}</dd>
            {/exp:weblog:entries}

{!-- Workers Comp --}
            {exp:weblog:entries weblog="products" entry_id="52"}
                <dt><a href="{title_permalink=/products/product/}">{title}</a></dt>
                <dd>{prod_short_desc}</dd>
            {/exp:weblog:entries}

{!-- Specialty Programs --}
            {exp:weblog:entries weblog="products" entry_id="53"}
                <dt><a href="{title_permalink=/products/product/}">{title}</a></dt>
                <dd>{prod_short_desc}</dd>
            {/exp:weblog:entries}

{!-- All Products --}
            {exp:weblog:entries weblog="products" entry_id="66"}
                <dt><a href="       {title_permalink=/products/product/}">See all our Products</a></dt>
                <dd>{prod_short_desc}</dd>
            {/exp:weblog:entries}
            </dl>

        </div> <!-- /main-content -->


        <div id="secondary-content">

            {embed='includes/sidebars-static' entryID="{entryID}"}

        </div>  <!-- /secondary-content -->

    </div> <!-- /content-wrapper -->

{!-- copyright, footer links, etc. --}
{embed="includes/global-footer"}

</div> <!-- /centering-content-wrapper -->

{!-- hook to put anything necessary right before the body tag, e.g. Google Analytics code --}
{embed="includes/global-page-bottom"}
```

So on this page the header not showing up is "Products" and instead is showing up as three x'S vertically in its place. When viewing the page source after the page loads the titles that are not showing are typically in an  tag like in this page's case.

I believe this is EE 1.

Let me know if you need any other code!

Comment: Are you using EE1.x or EE2.x?

Comment: @AlexKendrick i think EE1.X

Answer (score 1):

assign_variable has been replaced in EE with preload_replace in EE2!

It's only assigning the var, it's not calling it.

I would suggest reading how EE works http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/how_to/building_a_simple_news_site.html

Comment: Thank you! Reading this now...so preload_replace needs to replace assign_variable?

Comment: yeah. Is that all that you have in your template what you pasted above?

Comment: I just added the entire file's code. I didnt write the template so again forgive me for anything I may not know!

Comment: ok, so even if you update the instances of assign_var to preload_replace, it still won't output any code. Also preload_replace is for EE2 only. Work out what version of EE you're using, have a read at the docs in terms of how to output content from your weblogs/channels and you'll be in a better place.

Comment: It all looks like it checks out...you can see my full code above, but what i read looks like its applying to a newer version so just guessing here my code looks right. I am attempting in the CMS platform to view the code version like in those docs but i dont have that option in EE1.6.7

Comment: here are the docs for EE1 http://ee1docs.com/quick_start/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ways you can start to debug this:

1) Look at the rendered HTML source (view source after the page is loaded). What do you see for the `title` tag? Including this in your original question will probably help you get a better answer.

2) Run the HTML source through an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: There are errors but none I can see that would effect how the title is displaying. I added the tag in my original question But I dont know where in the world to get to that HTML code to edit and troubleshoot...my EE (uhnless im looking in the wrong place) does not have a code view

Comment: Judging from the extra template code you added, the html for your `<title>` tag is in this template (which you are embedding): `includes/browser-title-tag`.

Comment: yea I saw that and reading up know that thats where the issue is... But I have no idea my options to what to change it to or what to try to see if it gets fixed in IE10